# Documentation for socket errors

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I am creating a server-client application,this issue is that in the code below, I would get a failed to bind or failed to open socket message (see example code below).

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0){
    qDebug() << "ERROR netserver: opening socket";
    //more code here
}
```

or

```
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
   qDebug() << "ERROR netserver: binding to socket";
   //more code here
}
```

I am aware of C++ devs using the `getLastError()` but I do not find anything of the sort for sockets.

Does anyone know of a page/tutorial/wiki?

Comment: Google: errno, strerror, perror. On Windows, WSA_GetLastError. Qt may have a wrapper around those.

Comment: First of all, of you're using Qt why don't you use [the Qt network classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html)? Secondly, if you keep using low-level socket functions then how you get the error depends on your platform. On POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) you need to check `errno`. On Windows you need to use `WSAGetLastError`. Also, if you're on POSIX systems *use the manual pages*! (In a console use the [`man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) command, e.g. `man bind`).

Comment: @n.m. thank you, I shall have a look, for interest sake, how do you know of this since I have not come across these keywords before?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the heads up, I have learned something new, I shall apply it, thanks!

Comment: @KGCybeX By looking at the documentation. On Linux: [`man socket`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) lists the possible values of `errno` and what they mean. On Windows: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx), section "return value" says: "a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.".

Answer (score 0):

The failed to bind/open socket have typically a (non-developer) system error reason. These are not always that well reported :(

The reasons why that might happen, could be that the socket is already being listened on (ie. you are trying to run a second instance of the same program) or the previous socket haven't been closed properly by the OS after the previous program/instance exited. There are different ways to solve the last issue, but rather check it's not the first issue ;)

The other reason you might get these type of errors, is that the port being requested, is a privileged port, ie. anything less than 1024, which would require root (on Unix) type privilege.

On Unix, the friend there is "netstat -an" (Window I recall have a similar command)